# How to add text to new line

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to add text to new line.

My code:

```
TextField text = new TextField();

TextArea area = new Area();

String txt = text.getValue().toString();

area.setValue("\n" + txt);
```

When I click in my button I see my value from TextField. I want new text in new line in TextArea. Please help.

Comment: Why did you delete your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319340/copy-from-textfield-to-textarea/29319423#29319423? Normally you "accept" the answer to indicate that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to append that new value to the existing one and set that.  Something along the lines of:

```
area.setValue(area.getValue() + "\n" + txt);
```

The Vaadin TextArea has no direct way to append.  Also the rules in java, when to use `+` for stringsapply.  Consider using a `StringBuffer`, if you do this alot.

Comment: **"\n"** doesn't produce a new/break line, I'm having the same issue.
using Vaadin 7.7.7

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
area.setValue("\n" + txt);
```

Use

```
area.setValue(area.getValue + "\n" + txt);
```

This will ADD text, not REPLACE

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add the new line at the end. You will avoid having an empty line at the beginning in your TextArea.

E.g. `outputTextArea.setValue(outputTextArea.getValue() + input.getValue() + "\n");`

Furthermore: Make sure to use a **TextArea** and not a **TextField**, because line breaks with "\n" won't work in **TextField**!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Vaadin works with browsers, so normal scape characters doesn't work, ie: you cannot use '\n' on normal `Label`. Instead of it do the following:

```
label.setCaptionAsHtml(true);
label.setValue(label.getValue()+"<br>");
```

If you are using a `TextArea`, you can use `'\n'` as usual.
In case of `TextFiel`, you cannot write multiple lines, as it would convert it in a `TextArea` and this behavior is deprecated.